# Model hide mutators and nested fields

Tags: laravel

> Here is my **JSON** return

```
{
    "product": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Glory Cookware",
        "barcode": "1234567891234",
        "local_code_id": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "description": null
    },
    "calculations": {
        "product_quantity_in_warehouses": 1580,
        "avgSellingPriceBeforeTax": 901.7085714285713,
        "avgSellingPriceAfterTax": 1027.9477714285713,
        "creditPriceInWarehousesBeforeTax": 1530828,
        "creditPriceInWarehousesAfterTax": 1745143.92
    }
}
```

> What I am trying to do:

In the `Product.php` model I am trying to hide `calculations.creditPriceInWarehousesBeforeTax`.

> What I have tried:

I have tried to use `toArray()` method in the `Product.php` mode.

```
public function toArray()
{
    $hidden = ['calculations.creditPriceInWarehousesBeforeTax'];
    // Also tried ['creditPriceInWarehousesBeforeTax']
    $this -> hidden = $hidden;
    return parent::toArray();
}
```

> Expected behavior VS what happened

The JSON result should not return the `calculations.creditPriceInWarehousesBeforeTax` but what happened is that it return with the JSON.

> NOTE

`calculations` are a mutator that I have created to append it as an attribute.

Comment: Please post model code, esp the mutator function

Comment: You question is very unclear and the formatting is sub optimal